# g++,How to find where there is a error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, segmentation-fault

Guys!
I have written a c++ source.
But I find someplace there is a error.

"Segmentation fault: 11"

But I don't know the details about the error and where to fix?

Do you guys knows some commands can show where the error is.

Thanks

Comment: Post some code, especially where you deal with pointers.  Clearly you have a pointer that is invalid, causing you to access memory you shouldn't.

Comment: Ahh, the fabled `fix_bugs -all` command.  Few know of it, even fewer have mastered it.

Comment: This is incredible---perhaps the most pristine, textbook example of how to ask a bad question that I've ever seen.

Answer (score 4):

With `gcc` generated code you typically use a `gdb`-based tool or `gdb` itself. Just run

```
gdb <program>
```

... and then inside `gdb`:

```
run <arguments>
```

... and it will stop where the crash happens.

To get reasonable information about the program location you want to compile with debug information,i.e., using the `-g` option. To avoid confusion you might want to compile without optimization, i.e., without any `-O...` option. However, some errors are only triggered when optimization is turned on (note: these are generally still errors in your code and **not** in the optimizer).

Answer (score 1):

Use the GNU Debugger (GDB). Add break points and run the code. Here is where you can find stuff. http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbtoc.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your program is trying to access an invalid (non-existent) address.  It is also possible that it's trying to access misaligned data.  I've seen this before when attempting to access misaligned structures.

Read up on segmentation faults: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault